# How do i use the groupby function on dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, analytics

**Input** Dataframe:

```
      Last Updated  Downloads             Category  
0             2018      10000       ART_AND_DESIGN  
1             2018     500000       ART_AND_DESIGN  
2             2018    5000000       ART_AND_DESIGN  
3             2018   50000000       ART_AND_DESIGN  
4             2018     100000       ART_AND_DESIGN  
           ...        ...                  ...  
10838         2017       1000              MEDICAL  
10839         2015       1000  BOOKS_AND_REFERENCE  
10840         2018   10000000            LIFESTYLE
```

**The problem statement is**: "For the years 2016,2017,2018 what is the category of apps that have got the most and the least downloads"

To solve this I used:

```
df1 = df_year_d.groupby(['Last Updated','Category']).sum()
print(df1)
```

```
                                    Downloads
Last Updated Category                        
2010         FAMILY                    100000
2011         BOOKS_AND_REFERENCE      1000000
             BUSINESS                    1000
             FAMILY                     50000
             GAME                    10100000
             LIBRARIES_AND_DEMO       1000000
             LIFESTYLE                 100000
             TOOLS                    5156100
2012         BUSINESS                   10000
             COMMUNICATION               1000
             FAMILY                    711210
             FINANCE                   100000
             GAME                     1050000
             HEALTH_AND_FITNESS       1100000
             LIBRARIES_AND_DEMO      10000000
             MEDICAL                   120000
             PHOTOGRAPHY               500000
             PRODUCTIVITY              100000
             SHOPPING                  100000
             TOOLS                     200000
2013         BOOKS_AND_REFERENCE         2000
             BUSINESS                   10300
             COMMUNICATION             151000
             EDUCATION                  50000
             FAMILY                  50338310
             FINANCE                    60100
             GAME                    40265250
             HEALTH_AND_FITNESS         10000
             HOUSE_AND_HOME            100000
             LIBRARIES_AND_DEMO       6000000
                                      ...
2018         BOOKS_AND_REFERENCE   1880913110
             BUSINESS               975227003
             COMICS                  55201050
             COMMUNICATION        32548874886
             DATING                 262259557
             EDUCATION              842800000
             ENTERTAINMENT         2836150000
             EVENTS                  15410330
             FAMILY                9020112207
             FINANCE                872763824
             FOOD_AND_DRINK         271663081
             GAME                 33052192901
             HEALTH_AND_FITNESS    1568697276
             HOUSE_AND_HOME         161847101
             LIBRARIES_AND_DEMO      16283100
             LIFESTYLE              468085968
             MAPS_AND_NAVIGATION    702264990
             MEDICAL                 50556517
             NEWS_AND_MAGAZINES    7491323670
             PARENTING               31140010
             PERSONALIZATION       2130701875
             PHOTOGRAPHY           9402062515
             PRODUCTIVITY         13963101723
             SHOPPING              3243802640
             SOCIAL               13924137461
             SPORTS                1540744703
             TOOLS                10633528879
             TRAVEL_AND_LOCAL      6846181981
             VIDEO_PLAYERS         5928936510
             WEATHER                407227020

[188 rows x 1 columns]
```

Now I need the Category which is Max and Min in the three respective years 2016,2017,2018
Please suggest any efficient way to solve this query in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), so only processing rows which are necessary (reason is less rows processing is better performance).

Because you want `Category` by some years, first create `DataFrame` by `as_index=False` in aggregation `sum` and then use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and 
[`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) for index of minimal and maximal values per groups, so possible use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for selecting, [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) is used for convert rows to column:

```
df1 = df_year_d[df_year_d['Last Updated'].isin([2016,2017,2018])]
df1 = df_year_d.groupby(['Last Updated','Category'], as_index=False).sum()


df1 = df1.loc[df1.groupby('Last Updated')['Downloads'].agg(['idxmin','idxmax']).stack()]
df1.set_index("Last Updated", inplace=True)
df1=df1.loc[['2016','2017','2018']]


print(df1)
    Last Updated             Category  Downloads
7           2016             BUSINESS         10
6           2016  BOOKS_AND_REFERENCE      10000
14          2017         PRODUCTIVITY         10
9           2017       ART_AND_DESIGN    2660000
16          2018    AUTO_AND_VEHICLES        100
15          2018       ART_AND_DESIGN   84345000
```

Another idea is sortig by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and using [`GroupBy.nth`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html) for first and last rows per groups:

```
df1 = df_year_d[df_year_d['Last Updated'].isin([2016,2017,2018])]
df1 = df_year_d.groupby(['Last Updated','Category'], as_index=False).sum()

df1 = (df1.sort_values(['Last Updated','Downloads'])
          .groupby('Last Updated', as_index=False)
          .nth([0,-1]))
print(df1)
    Last Updated           Category  Downloads
7           2016           BUSINESS         10
8           2016            FINANCE      10000
14          2017       PRODUCTIVITY         10
9           2017     ART_AND_DESIGN    2660000
16          2018  AUTO_AND_VEHICLES        100
15          2018     ART_AND_DESIGN   84345000
```

Comment: @Aditya Patil Now I realised my solution was not correct, in second lines is necessary `df1` instead `df_year_d`. It means in first step data are filtered. Answer was edited.

Comment: Could you explain the third line of code of the first solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use Sqlalchemy to convert dataframe into a reflection of database and use a SQL query to achieve the result.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
engine = create_engine('sqlite://',echo = False)
sql = df.to_sql('Table_Name', con = engine)
query=""
engine.execute(query).fetchall()
```

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind but I'm not so good with SQL can you tell me what SQL query do I require here?

Answer (score 0):

Let's understand by taking an example.

```
# Sample dataset --> df

      Last Updated  Downloads Category
0           2016         10    CAT-A
1           2016         20    CAT-A
2           2016         10    CAT-A
3           2016         20    CAT-B
4           2016         30    CAT-B
5           2016         20    CAT-B
6           2016         35    CAT-C
7           2016         20    CAT-C
8           2017         25    CAT-A
9           2017         25    CAT-A
10          2017         30    CAT-A
11          2017         70    CAT-B
12          2017         70    CAT-B
13          2017         80    CAT-B
14          2017         10    CAT-C
15          2017         10    CAT-C
16          2018         15    CAT-A
17          2018         25    CAT-A
18          2018         15    CAT-A
19          2018         20    CAT-B
20          2018         15    CAT-B
21          2018         10    CAT-B
22          2018         90    CAT-C
23          2018        150    CAT-C
```

```
# Filtering dataframe on years and summing up all entries category-wise
my_filtered_df = df[df['Last Updated'].between(2016, 2018, inclusive=True)].groupby(['Last Updated','Category']).sum()

                  Downloads
          Last Updated     Category           
2016         CAT-A            40
             CAT-B            70
             CAT-C            55
2017         CAT-A            80
             CAT-B           220
             CAT-C            20
2018         CAT-A            55
             CAT-B            45
             CAT-C           240
```

```
min_downloads = my_filtered_df.loc[my_filtered_df.groupby("Last Updated").Downloads.idxmin()].reset_index()

     Last Updated Category  Downloads
0          2016    CAT-A         40
1          2017    CAT-C         20
2          2018    CAT-B         45
```

```
max_downloads = my_filtered_df.loc[my_filtered_df.groupby("Last Updated").Downloads.idxmax()].reset_index()

     Last Updated Category  Downloads
0          2016    CAT-B         70
1          2017    CAT-B        220
2          2018    CAT-C        240>
```

**PS:** Thanks @jezrael for pointing out the flaw in the previous approach.

Comment: Can you add output?

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for the suggestion, I've added sample dataframe output for better understanding.

Comment: hmmm, I think your solution is wrong, because OP need top categories by top values, check my answer.

Comment: @jezrael Yes you were right, I misunderstood the problem and there was an intrinsic flaw in the previous approach. I have corrected the approach and given example output as well.

Comment: @jezrael Changed the approach further to prevent infringement of your answer and using a little different approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204131/discussion-between-rohit-and-jezrael).